# How to find all documents with a particular filed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code, but this is pulling all the documents and showing the two mentioned fields. But I want to get only those documents which have these fields.

```
.get(function(req, res) {
       partment.find({},'unitID UnitType',function(err, apartments) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err)    
           res.json(apartments);
       });
 }
```

Any Idea how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
payment.find({unitId: {$exists: true}, UnitType: {$exists: true}}, ...)
```